# make save as button in GUI matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to build a small project using matlab GUI .

my project simply is to load  an image  in GUI and make some change and then save the resulted image .
my only problem is to make a button  for save as option ... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add the following code inside the button callback

```
[file,path]=uiputfile({'*.bmp','BMP'},'Save Image As');
imwrite(x,fullfile(path, file),'bmp');
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to do the saving action when clicking the button, right?
If yes, then it should be easy.

1. Drag and create a new button;
2. Open the editor by right clicking the button;
3. write your saving code under the function name like:
          function *ButtonName*_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

[image]

Hope that can help you.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer
I know how to do that but my question what is the code for a save as button